# Where (if anywhere) should I report BOTH problems occuring with minor changes?

Tags: support

I've formulated [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909317/rowstyle-in-datagrid-working-only-partially) and someone changed the indentation from two spaces to three. That's **waaay** too minor change, hardly detectable **and** not really how many feel the code should be formatted (some do, of course, but that's not a reason to mess with anothers' posts).

So I wonder if I should report said user or just roll-back and let it go. I'm not emotionally involved so I'd prefer to be lazy and not do a jack. However, I still feel obliged to ask if an action is required.

That also begs the other question. Should I report the users who approved that change. If so, where? (And, as in the first case, I'm still lazy, so if not expected, I'd prefer to just go about my lonely life.)

Comment: The fact that the indentation changed is likely just a mistake, the edit was removing extra spacing that came before the code, which arguably does make it easier to read, at least just a little bit. The edit should have removed 4 spaces from every line, rather than just select ones.

Comment: I think you only need to do something if someone tries to undo your rollback. If it doesn't start an edit war, just rolling it back is fine.

Comment: A link for the edit in question: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9103767 I agree that it improved readability.

Comment: @KevinB You're absolutely right. I stand there like an ass for posting ill-formatted code (which I usually am proud never to do). I went back and corrected it back. Shame on **me**!

Comment: @Trobbins So do I. Please see the comment to KevinB above. My bad. I'm first to admit when I stand corrected. This is my brains telling me it's time for bed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an edit is made to your question that you do not approve of, you can either reject it before it is approved, or roll it back after it is approved. If the same edit is made again, instead of rolling it back again, flag your question for moderator attention using a custom flag explaining the situation.

---

In this case, the edit was made with good intentions, but wasn't done completely right. The editor should have removed 4 spaces from every line.